# Setting permissions in cakephp Pages controller

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I followed Andrew Perkins [excellent tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM) on setting up permissions in CakePHP 2.0.

My question, however, relates to how to use the allow and deny method in the Pages controller. Currently I have `$this->Auth->allow('display')` which allows all methods in the Pages controller to be view.

What if I only want the home page allowed but the rest denied? How do I code that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have copied the PageController.php to your app/Controller folder. Then, add a *beforeFilter* callback method and set access based on the passed page parameter:

```
public function beforeFilter() {   
    // Use $this->request->pass to get the requested page name/id   
    // Decide on access with $this->Auth->allow() 
}
```

This should solve your problem.

You can find more information on request's lifecycle in [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks). That's pretty useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code?
You can out it into your PageController or into your Controller directly

```
$views = array ('index'); //array of view that you want allow
$this->Auth->allow($views);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But the problem is that the Pages controller has 1 method for output which is display (the page is actually determined by the passed parameter in the method) so allowing or denying display covers all Pages views.

Comment: try to put my lines into your controller.php not in the PageController

Comment: It won't work as the view I am using is display, regardless of the page shown (CakePHP convention).

Comment: change undex to display, because if you want to allow only a view you have to do that into your controllero not into the PagesController or in other Controller